# Rails - how to run a cmd line script and display the output in real time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to let a user select a script to run from the cmd line and see the output of the script as it runs in (close to) real time. I know this isn't safe, it's for an internal tool used by a small team to allow a level of self service.

Here's a quick example of a ruby script that runs something on the cmd line and displaying the output in real time. What i can't figure out is how to get this to work from rails.

```
cmd = %q[echo '3...'; sleep 1;
         echo '2...'; sleep 1;
         echo '1...'; sleep 1;
         echo 'Liftoff!']

puts '------ beginning command ------'
output_log = []
IO.popen(cmd).each do |line|
  puts line
  output_log << "[#{Time.now}] #{line}"
end.close # Without close, you won't be able to access $?
puts '------ done with command ------'

puts "The command's exit code was: #{$?.exitstatus}"
puts 'Here is the log:'
puts output_log.join('')
```

Are there any existing gems for this? Can I have an ajax request call a file that runs the command, outputs to a buffer, and then I can flush the buffer as the script runs and send a response back to the page it runs on? I'm even fine with using iframes if it helps.

Any help or pointing in the right direction is hugely appreciated!

Comment: What are these scripts doing? Is there a way to just put the scripts in a repository and have people run them locally? For this to be done in a scalable way, i.e. on more than 1 host, you will likely need to persist the progress of each script somewhere. For instance, you might store it in a database.

Comment: The scripts are to allow non-technical users self admin their testing environments from a GUI. Scale isn't an issue, but I was afraid writing to a db or a flat file somewhere was my only option. Rails just does so much for you, so I thought it might have a gem to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this , you will need a delayed job or sidekick object - to actually run the script.
Use ruby `IO.popen` method to execute command and read the output and flush it into database meanwhile.
On your webapplication you just poll data via ajax from that database object.